# How would life evolve in an infinite McDonalds?

Tags: evolution

This isn't actually my own question, but i saw this post circulating and thought that Worldbuilding Stackexchange would have a ball with it.

[image]

Comment: Is this a reference to SCP-3008?

Comment: I do have to concur with one of the comments in the image - I'm not sure what the question's asking, and there's no way of asking for clarification. Moreover, though, I don't think this is really a question about building a world, so that would make it off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Initially, macro-organisms would mostly die off for the reasons [Nuclear Hoagie describes in his answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/202873/57832) or just become nomadic forever as the travel farther and farther out to exploit new resources, but near ground zero, thermophiles similar to those found near geothermal vents may find a way to live off the constant heat and available nutrients found in the deep friers.

Eventually, life will learn to come out of the deep-fryers though and take advantage of other energy sources like the warming lamps, grills, and bun toasters.  Inevitably, a few organisms like raccoons or humans may have left a few faucets running before moving on, filling large areas of the McDonalds with abundant water and breaking large areas of tile floors down into soil allow some manner of plant life to take hold.  Once an appropriate ecosystem of plant like organisms start to grow from the water and heating lamps, macroscopic consumers will follow suit.  Eventually, you'll have a thriving ecosystem powered by the McDonald's various heat producing things, and the endless supply of flowing water.

Answer (score 1):

**It wouldn't.**

Most animals don't eat other animals, so the vast majority will die of starvation within weeks. Animals have no means of harnessing the energy of the Sun, so an infinite McDonald's that contains a finite number of animals only has a fixed amount of energy available. That energy will be lost over time to inefficiencies in biology, meaning that sooner or later, there will be no useful energy available for any organism.

A food chain that consists only of consumers (animals) and has no producers (plants) will inevitably fail as the amount of available usable energy is constantly dwindling. Most of your animals will die very quickly, and none will survive on evolutionary timescales